# Using text indent- is it good semantics ??

Tags: html, css, seo, text-indent

this is a pretty straightforward question :

Introduction : i have seen on a lot of websites that make use of alot of images use the property text indent to hide text that is on an image , the text is usually hidden using text-indent . so i guess the text the is visible on the image is for the end user to see and the same text that has been hidden using text-indent is for the serch engines to crawl :

here's an example of what i am saying :

```
.main{
      text-align: center;

    }
    .main img{
      margin-top: 100px;
      height: 40%;
      width: 40%;
    }
    .main div{      
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      text-indent: -9999px;
    }
```

HTML code :

```
<div class="main">
      <img src="http://www.grammar.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/12-love-idioms_big-01.png" alt="temp image">
      <div><p>Phoenix Kids Daycare Bangalore, follows a play based system integrated with a curriculum conforming to the global best teaching practices. Our focus is on interactive learning-center and sessions where children apply what they learn and learn what they apply. They then begin to take ownership for their learning and become lifelong learners.</p></div>
 </div>
```

now is this an outdated practice ? is this still efficient ? in reality is it considered semantic ?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/419d4wt6/)

though its a relatively simple question i am asking its important as , as i would like my side to have semantic HTML .

Thank you.

Tenali.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Comment: Asking how search engines will display/rank/parse your site is off topic

Comment: "is it better for search engines to crawl ? is doing this(that is adding text and than using text-indent to hide the text , just for images that usually contain a lot of useful information) better for overall search optimization and website optimization ?" is asking how will the search engines parse and crawl your site

Comment: @random edited ! now take off the down vote .

Comment: A close vote is not the same as a downvote. You need to find the user who downvoted you instead.

Comment: @random ur in-considerate attitude was of great help to me ! Thanks a ton .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good reason not to use the -9999px method is that the browser has to draw a 9999px box for each element that this is applied to. Obviously, that potentially creates quite a performance hit, especially if you're applying it to multiple elements.

Alternative methods include this one[Link](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/)

```
text-indent: 100%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;
```

..or alternatively (from [Link](http://bustoutsolutions.com/blog/2009/10/08/better-alternative-to-text-indent-9999px)

```
height: 0; overflow: hidden; padding-top: 20px;
```

(where 'padding-top' is the height you want the element to be).

I think the first method is neater, since it lets you set height in the normal way, but I've found the second one to work better in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, this approach is likely to increase SEO (Search Engine Optimization). As you rightly stated, Search Engines cannot read images in that format, but your information is stored within a div, so from the point of view of a search engine crawler, the information is not image data.

When people think of this approach, they normally do it with the intention of increasing search engine results. However, offering alternative content for an image is also a great way for screen readers to interrupt your images. Using your example, without the div explaining the contents of the image, a blind or poorly sighted person would not be able to understand the content of the image.

Comment: if not the div than what should i really use <p> </p> ??

Comment: In this context, I'd use a <p> tag as it's primarily informative text of similar nature.

Answer (score 0):

This can be considered cloaking as you are giving the search engines content that a user cannot read.

- https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en

You can use the alt-tag to further describe the picture. If its an infographic or such I would not recommend you use your described methods for explaining the infographic to search engines.

- https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016?hl=en (Image publishing guidelines Google)